# How can I return last change parrNum from this function

Tags: php, recursion

How can I get the last `parrNum` in this recursive function?

```
function findCountOfParents($arrayName,$case,$parrNum=0)
{   
    foreach ($arrayName as $key) 
    {

        if ($case==$key['ID'] && $key['parent_id']!=0) 
        {
            $p_id = $key['parent_id'];
            $parrNum ++;
            findCountOfParents($arrayName,$p_id,$parrNum);
        }   
    }
    return $parrNum;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the return value of the recursive call back to the variable.

```
function findCountOfParents($arrayName,$case,$parrNum=0)
{   
    foreach ($arrayName as $key) 
    {

        if ($case==$key['ID'] && $key['parent_id']!=0) 
        {
            $p_id = $key['parent_id'];
            $parrNum = findCountOfParents($arrayName,$p_id,$parrNum + 1);
        }   
    }
    return $parrNum;
}
```